# Spring cloud stream + After a producer error subscription to the IN channel breaks

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 3.1.1 version.
Looking to handle intermittent kafka publishing failures.

Below is our existing configuration,

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: execute;supplyPayment;
      routing-expression:
    stream:
      kafka:
        default:
          producer:
            errorChannelEnabled: true
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9094
          producer-properties:
            retries: 20
            max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 10
            linger.ms: 100
            request.timeout.ms: 3000
            batch.size: 20000
            retry.backoff.ms: 1000
      bindings:
        execute-in-0:
          destination: test-in-source
          group: consumer-dedupe
          concurrency: 2
        execute-out-0:
          destination: test-out-topic
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
```

Able to get hold of the producer error using ServiceActivator.

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void handle(final ErrorMessage em) {
        log.error("Error caught" + em.toString());
    }
```

Was expecting no exception to be thrown as we have the ServiceActivator implemented, but we see TimeoutException thrown

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test-out-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
2021-12-09|06:11:25.267 ERROR o.s.c.s.f.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder - intuit_tid= provider_id= entity_type= Failure was detected during execution of the reactive function 'execute'
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@48ea8766]; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test-out-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1046], headers={intuit_originatingip=192.19.0.1, entity_version=v1, entity_processing_status=SUCCESS, PIPELINE_ID=1, target-protocol=kafka, ROUTING_INFO=RoutingInfo(currentPipelineNode=PipelineNode{id=0, type=null, sourceTopic=null, pipelineNodeStatus=null, errorHandlerClassName=null, errorTopicName=null}, executedPipelineNodeList=[PipelineNode{id=1, type=PROCESSOR, sourceTopic=idx-payment-source, pipelineNodeStatus=SUCCESS, errorHandlerClassName=com.intuit.fdp.enrichment.messagemesh.errorhandler.impl.ContinueProcessingErrorHandler, errorTopicName=null}, PipelineNode{id=2, type=PROCESSOR, sourceTopic=idx-payment-source, pipelineNodeStatus=SUCCESS, errorHandlerClassName=com.intuit.fdp.enrichment.messagemesh.errorhandler.impl.ContinueProcessingErrorHandler, errorTopicName=null}]), id=d9be7b62-711d-2200-2da7-775bc9ed4bbd, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1639059024747, intuit_realmid=123148525896109, intuit_iddomain=test, timestamp=1639059025243, test=testValue, intuit_tid=978bd234-48cc-4914-8afc-9c84be5c467e, intuit_offeringid=Intuit.platform.qbo.dtx.ui, deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, intuit_locale=en_US, kafka_receivedTopic=idx-payment-source, kafka_offset=2, entity_type=PaymentTransactionEvent, entity_namespace=com.intuit.idx.event.payment.v1, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@597cf885, intuit_country=US, provider_id=1234, intuit_corpid=Jacinda, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_groupId=consumer-dedupe}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.doOnNext
    org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$bindFunctionToDestinations$9(FunctionConfiguration.java:501)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ Flux.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$bindFunctionToDestinations$9(FunctionConfiguration.java:501)
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$null$7(FunctionConfiguration.java:518)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:196)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmit(FluxFlatMap.java:542)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:1006)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMetricsFuseable$MetricsFuseableSubscriber.onNext(MonoMetricsFuseable.java:132)
        at 
---
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test-out-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

And also the errorHandler is logging the producer error,

```
ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaSendFailureException: nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-out-topic-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1044], headers={intuit_originatingip=192.19.0.1, entity_version=v1, entity_processing_status=SUCCESS, PIPELINE_ID=1, target-protocol=kafka, ROUTING_INFO=RoutingInfo(currentPipelineNode=PipelineNode{id=0, type=null, sourceTopic=null, pipelineNodeStatus=null, errorHandlerClassName=null, errorTopicName=null}, executedPipelineNodeList=[PipelineNode{id=1, type=PROCESSOR, sourceTopic=idx-payment-source, pipelineNodeStatus=SUCCESS, errorHandlerClassName=com.intuit.fdp.enrichment.messagemesh.errorhandler.impl.ContinueProcessingErrorHandler, errorTopicName=null}, PipelineNode{id=2, type=PROCESSOR, sourceTopic=idx-payment-source, pipelineNodeStatus=SUCCESS, errorHandlerClassName=com.intuit.fdp.enrichment.messagemesh.errorhandler.impl.ContinueProcessingErrorHandler, errorTopicName=null}]), id=5ea18c46-1074-41bd-8ac6-adfc1aba7811, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1639058994738, intuit_realmid=123148525896109, intuit_iddomain=test, timestamp=1639058995246, test=testValue, intuit_tid=0a19feb2-e90c-4a3d-b9ef-94294bbd5ebd, intuit_offeringid=Intuit.platform.qbo.dtx.ui, deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, intuit_locale=en_US, kafka_receivedTopic=idx-payment-source, kafka_offset=1, entity_type=PaymentTransactionEvent, entity_namespace=com.intuit.idx.event.payment.v1, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@597cf885, intuit_country=US, provider_id=1234, intuit_corpid=Angela, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_groupId=consumer-dedupe}] [record=ProducerRecord(topic=test-out-topic, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = intuit_originatingip, value = [49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 57, 46, 48, 46, 49]), RecordHeader(key = entity_version, value = [118, 49]), RecordHeader(key = entity_processing_status, value = [83, 85, 67, 67, 69, 83, 83]), RecordHeader(key = PIPELINE_ID, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = target-protocol, value = [107, 97, 102, 107, 97]), RecordHeader(key = ROUTING_INFO, value = [123, 34, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 80, 105, 112, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 78, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 123, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 48, 44, 34, 103, 114, 111, 117, 112, 73, 100, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 97, 114, 116, 105, 102, 97, 99, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 114, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 73, 100, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 115, 34, 58, 91, 93, 44, 34, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 112, 105, 112, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 78, 111, 100, 101, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 67, 108, 97, 115, 115, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125, 44, 34, 101, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 101, 100, 80, 105, 112, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 78, 111, 100, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 34, 58, 91, 123, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 49, 44, 34, 103, 114, 111, 117, 112, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 115, 104, 34, 44, 34, 97, 114, 116, 105, 102, 97, 99, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 100, 101, 100, 117, 112, 101, 34, 44, 34, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 34, 48, 46, 49, 46, 49, 57, 34, 44, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 80, 82, 79, 67, 69, 83, 83, 79, 82, 34, 44, 34, 114, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 105, 100, 120, 45, 100, 101, 100, 117, 112, 101, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 115, 34, 58, 91, 93, 44, 34, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 34, 58, 34, 105, 100, 120, 45, 112, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 45, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 112, 105, 112, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 78, 111, 100, 101, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 34, 58, 34, 83, 85, 67, 67, 69, 83, 83, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 67, 108, 97, 115, 115, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 102, 100, 112, 46, 101, 110, 114, 105, 99, 104, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 115, 104, 46, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 104, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 46, 105, 109, 112, 108, 46, 67, 111, 110, 116, 105, 110, 117, 101, 80, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 105, 110, 103, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125, 44, 123, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 50, 44, 34, 103, 114, 111, 117, 112, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 115, 104, 34, 44, 34, 97, 114, 116, 105, 102, 97, 99, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 112, 101, 114, 115, 105, 115, 116, 34, 44, 34, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 34, 48, 46, 49, 46, 49, 57, 34, 44, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 80, 82, 79, 67, 69, 83, 83, 79, 82, 34, 44, 34, 114, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 105, 100, 120, 45, 100, 101, 100, 117, 112, 101, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 115, 34, 58, 91, 123, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 34, 52, 48, 48, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 67, 108, 97, 115, 115, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 102, 100, 112, 46, 101, 110, 114, 105, 99, 104, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 115, 104, 46, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 104, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 46, 105, 109, 112, 108, 46, 80, 117, 98, 108, 105, 115, 104, 84, 111, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 105, 100, 120, 45, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 45, 116, 111, 112, 105, 99, 34, 125, 44, 123, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 34, 42, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 67, 108, 97, 115, 115, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 102, 100, 112, 46, 101, 110, 114, 105, 99, 104, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 115, 104, 46, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 104, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 46, 105, 109, 112, 108, 46, 83, 116, 111, 112, 80, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 105, 110, 103, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125, 93, 44, 34, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 34, 58, 34, 105, 100, 120, 45, 112, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 45, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 112, 105, 112, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 78, 111, 100, 101, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 34, 58, 34, 83, 85, 67, 67, 69, 83, 83, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 67, 108, 97, 115, 115, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 102, 100, 112, 46, 101, 110, 114, 105, 99, 104, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 115, 104, 46, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 104, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 46, 105, 109, 112, 108, 46, 67, 111, 110, 116, 105, 110, 117, 101, 80, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 105, 110, 103, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125, 93, 125]), RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_realmid, value = [49, 50, 51, 49, 52, 56, 53, 50, 53, 56, 57, 54, 49, 48, 57]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_iddomain, value = [116, 101, 115, 116]), RecordHeader(key = test, value = [116, 101, 115, 116, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_tid, value = [48, 97, 49, 57, 102, 101, 98, 50, 45, 101, 57, 48, 99, 45, 52, 97, 51, 100, 45, 98, 57, 101, 102, 45, 57, 52, 50, 57, 52, 98, 98, 100, 53, 101, 98, 100]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_offeringid, value = [73, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 112, 108, 97, 116, 102, 111, 114, 109, 46, 113, 98, 111, 46, 100, 116, 120, 46, 117, 105]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_locale, value = [101, 110, 95, 85, 83]), RecordHeader(key = entity_type, value = [80, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 84, 114, 97, 110, 115, 97, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116]), RecordHeader(key = entity_namespace, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 105, 100, 120, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 112, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 118, 49]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_country, value = [85, 83]), RecordHeader(key = provider_id, value = [49, 50, 51, 52]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_corpid, value = [65, 110, 103, 101, 108, 97]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 116, 105, 110, 103, 105, 112, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 101, 110, 116, 105, 116, 121, 95, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 116, 101, 115, 116, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 116, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 111, 102, 102, 101, 114, 105, 110, 103, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 100, 101, 108, 105, 118, 101, 114, 121, 65, 116, 116, 101, 109, 112, 116, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 101, 110, 116, 105, 116, 121, 95, 112, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 105, 110, 103, 95, 115, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 80, 73, 80, 69, 76, 73, 78, 69, 95, 73, 68, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 116, 97, 114, 103, 101, 116, 45, 112, 114, 111, 116, 111, 99, 111, 108, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 101, 110, 116, 105, 116, 121, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 101, 110, 116, 105, 116, 121, 95, 110, 97, 109, 101, 115, 112, 97, 99, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 82, 79, 85, 84, 73, 78, 71, 95, 73, 78, 70, 79, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 102, 100, 112, 46, 101, 110, 114, 105, 99, 104, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 112, 105, 112, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 46, 112, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 115, 46, 82, 111, 117, 116, 105, 110, 103, 73, 110, 102, 111, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 114, 121, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 112, 114, 111, 118, 105, 100, 101, 114, 95, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 99, 111, 114, 112, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 114, 101, 97, 108, 109, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 105, 100, 100, 111, 109, 97, 105, 110, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=[B@dfd024f, timestamp=null)], headers={id=1823c929-83f7-4b15-358f-821b3ae843b4, timestamp=1639059115250}]
```

Looks like since the Timeout exception is thrown, the subscriber for the in channel is lost and seeing the below logged by the errorChannel,

```
ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application-1.execute-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[761], headers={intuit_originatingip=192.19.0.1, entity_version=[B@24abc8d8, test=[B@677453b9, intuit_tid=[B@20a8288, intuit_offeringid=[B@3feabc33, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, intuit_locale=en_US, kafka_receivedTopic=idx-payment-source, kafka_offset=5, entity_type=[B@45fd5e1e, entity_namespace=[B@513483, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@597cf885, intuit_country=US, provider_id=[B@5619f8c3, intuit_corpid=[B@3c78cd17, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1639059114780, kafka_groupId=consumer-dedupe, intuit_realmid=[B@135a7928, intuit_iddomain=test}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[761], headers={intuit_originatingip=192.19.0.1, entity_version=[B@24abc8d8, test=[B@677453b9, intuit_tid=[B@20a8288, intuit_offeringid=[B@3feabc33, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, intuit_locale=en_US, kafka_receivedTopic=idx-payment-source, kafka_offset=5, entity_type=[B@45fd5e1e, entity_namespace=[B@513483, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@597cf885, intuit_country=US, provider_id=[B@5619f8c3, intuit_corpid=[B@3c78cd17, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1639059114780, kafka_groupId=consumer-dedupe, intuit_realmid=[B@135a7928, intuit_iddomain=test}], headers={kafka_data=ConsumerRecord(topic = idx-payment-source, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 5, CreateTime = 1639059114780, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 1186, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = intuit_originatingip, value = [49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 57, 46, 48, 46, 49]), RecordHeader(key = entity_version, value = [118, 49]), RecordHeader(key = test, value = [116, 101, 115, 116, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_tid, value = [56, 49, 55, 53, 52, 55, 51, 54, 45, 101, 102, 97, 55, 45, 52, 102, 53, 48, 45, 98, 101, 101, 57, 45, 102, 50, 54, 48, 48, 56, 101, 49, 53, 48, 101, 48]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_offeringid, value = [73, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 112, 108, 97, 116, 102, 111, 114, 109, 46, 113, 98, 111, 46, 100, 116, 120, 46, 117, 105]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_locale, value = [101, 110, 95, 85, 83]), RecordHeader(key = entity_type, value = [80, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 84, 114, 97, 110, 115, 97, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116]), RecordHeader(key = entity_namespace, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 105, 100, 120, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 112, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 118, 49]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_country, value = [85, 83]), RecordHeader(key = provider_id, value = [84, 101, 115, 116, 80, 114, 111, 118, 49, 50, 51, 52]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_corpid, value = [74, 97, 99, 105, 110, 100, 97]), RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_realmid, value = [49, 50, 51, 49, 52, 56, 53, 50, 53, 56, 57, 54, 49, 48, 57]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_iddomain, value = [116, 101, 115, 116]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 116, 105, 110, 103, 105, 112, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 114, 121, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 105, 100, 100, 111, 109, 97, 105, 110, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@3609e9b), id=99a23404-032b-363c-ae7a-2e5f6cd83ef8, sourceData=ConsumerRecord(topic = idx-payment-source, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 5, CreateTime = 1639059114780, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 1186, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = intuit_originatingip, value = [49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 57, 46, 48, 46, 49]), RecordHeader(key = entity_version, value = [118, 49]), RecordHeader(key = test, value = [116, 101, 115, 116, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_tid, value = [56, 49, 55, 53, 52, 55, 51, 54, 45, 101, 102, 97, 55, 45, 52, 102, 53, 48, 45, 98, 101, 101, 57, 45, 102, 50, 54, 48, 48, 56, 101, 49, 53, 48, 101, 48]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_offeringid, value = [73, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 112, 108, 97, 116, 102, 111, 114, 109, 46, 113, 98, 111, 46, 100, 116, 120, 46, 117, 105]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_locale, value = [101, 110, 95, 85, 83]), RecordHeader(key = entity_type, value = [80, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 84, 114, 97, 110, 115, 97, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116]), RecordHeader(key = entity_namespace, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 46, 105, 100, 120, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 112, 97, 121, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 118, 49]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_country, value = [85, 83]), RecordHeader(key = provider_id, value = [84, 101, 115, 116, 80, 114, 111, 118, 49, 50, 51, 52]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_corpid, value = [74, 97, 99, 105, 110, 100, 97]), RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_realmid, value = [49, 50, 51, 49, 52, 56, 53, 50, 53, 56, 57, 54, 49, 48, 57]), RecordHeader(key = intuit_iddomain, value = [116, 101, 115, 116]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 116, 105, 110, 103, 105, 112, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 114, 121, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 117, 105, 116, 95, 105, 100, 100, 111, 109, 97, 105, 110, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@3609e9b), timestamp=1639059117896}] for original GenericMessage [payload=byte[761], headers={intuit_originatingip=192.19.0.1, entity_version=[B@24abc8d8, test=[B@677453b9, intuit_tid=[B@20a8288, intuit_offeringid=[B@3feabc33, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, intuit_locale=en_US, kafka_receivedTopic=idx-payment-source, kafka_offset=5, entity_type=[B@45fd5e1e, entity_namespace=[B@513483, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@597cf885, intuit_country=US, provider_id=[B@5619f8c3, intuit_corpid=[B@3c78cd17, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1639059114780, kafka_groupId=consumer-dedupe, intuit_realmid=[B@135a7928, intuit_iddomain=test}]
```

Once this occurs, even after the kafka issue is resolved, the application is not able to recover unless restarted.

Here is the sample project, https://github.com/ssruthisree/reactive-processor-kafka aggregate is my Function that is publishing. To replicate the error steps done: 1) Start appln 2) Verify messages consumed by aggregate and published to transform topic. 3) Delete the transform topic 4) Exception thrown from Producer not caught by Flux's onError.

How can we avoid the subscription failure on producer errors? And continue consuming once kafka issue is resolved without application restart?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are having a *reactive* function while trying to use the error handling mechanism designed for *imperative* functions.
That will not work since we (the spring-cloud-stream framework) can not handle any reactive errors since we simply don't see them.
Imperative functions are message handlers. They are invoked once per message, hence we can wrap it around and handle errors.
Reactive functions are invoked only once when stream is initialized. Form that point the control is within the reactive API, so you must use extensive error handling support provided by reactive API (e.g., `doOnError(..)` etc.)

Your error `Dispatcher has no subscribers . . .`, simply means that your reactive subscription failed (due to some processing error) and unsubscribed from the channel (stream is no longer functioning).

Comment: Thanks for your response @oleg-zhurakousky. As suggested by you, tried using the reactor error handling and code snippet in next comment

Comment: Code snippet below,
`
@Bean
public Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> aggregate() {
  return inbound ->
      inbound
          .log()
          .map(
              s -> {
                if (s.equals("foo")) {
                  log.info("Going to throw");
                  throw new RuntimeException("run time exception");
                }
                log.info("no Exception");
                return s;
              })
          .onErrorContinue(
              (err, i) -> {
                log.info("log for onErrorContinue={}", i);
              });
}
`

Comment: The exception thrown from the flux bock is being caught by the reactor’s error handler (onErrorContinue/ resume etc)
Tried replicating the Kafka error, by deleting the topic the Function is attempting to publish to and the reactor’s error handler was **not** invoked and the Error was thrown from the Producer and ultimately gets into error dropped block. Once the exception is thrown as mentioned earlier, the subscriber stops.

Comment: Logs below,
2021-12-14 07:47:08.970 ERROR 79948 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{98, 97, 114}' to topic transform:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic transform not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2021-12-14 07:47:08.976  INFO 79948 --- [container-0-C-1] reactor.Flux.Map.1                       : cancel()

Comment: 2021-12-14 07:47:08.977  INFO 79948 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'application.aggregate-in-0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-12-14 07:47:08.977 ERROR 79948 --- [container-0-C-1] onfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder : Failure was detected during execution of the reactive function 'aggregate'
2021-12-14 07:47:08.982 ERROR 79948 --- [container-0-C-1] r.kafka.ReactiveProcessorApplication     : invoked hooks on errordropped

Comment: We see that the Flux stream returned has no access to the exception thrown outside the Function with reactor error handling. 
Is there any solution available at the Producer level to be able to handle such exceptions and mainly avoid the subscriber from stopping?

Comment: as I said, you provide your own implementation of onError within your function implementation as we have to access to it

Comment: The control does not get to the onError implementation on the Flux, when producer error occurs.

Comment: May be you can create a bare minimum reproducible sample and post it to github so we can take a look, otherwise I don't know what's going on other then what I have already said

Comment: Here is the sample project, https://github.com/ssruthisree/reactive-processor-kafka.git aggregate is my Function that is publishing. To replicate the error steps done: 1) Start appln 2) Verify messages consumed by aggregate and published to transform topic. 3) Delete the transform topic 4) Exception thrown from Producer not caught by Flux's onError.

Comment: Your application doesn't do anything and the docker yaml file contains errors (`services.kafka.environment contains {"KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE": false}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string`). Please provide reproducible sample with instructions

Comment: Have made few updates to the repo shared and verified that I'm able to execute the same on my local. And have added a detailed  readme to replicate the error. Please let me know if this works. https://github.com/ssruthisree/reactive-processor-kafka.git

Comment: All I see is `2021-12-20 14:58:33.859  WARN 12272 --- [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 31 : {transform=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

Comment: Correct, and after a minute (the default buffer time), you should start seeing "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.aggregate-in-0'" . Before this occurs, if I recreate my topic, I'm able to continue with consuming messages as part of aggregate function. But after the dispatcher fails, not able to recover, even if the topic is recreated.

Comment: Does the latest code github.com/ssruthisree/reactive-processor-kafka.git  work for you? We are blocked on this and any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will look again when I get a chance, but i would say switch to imperative API. Given the fact that the binders are still non-reactive you are not getting any reactive features (i.e., back-pressure, buffering etc) . . . only API compatibility.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky we run into the same issue. Adding onErrorResume to ignore error does not help. We use flux in order to use `flux.delayElements` to delay message dispatch. Any suggestion what would be the best way to do this in non-reactive way? use Thread.sleep?